# XML to JSON when there is <![CDATA[]]> in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, cdata, simplexml

I am trying to convert a group of xml files from a directory to json format but in my xml there are CDATA, son when it converts the CDATA went empty. I was using simplexml_load_file($xml) but I read that doesn't get CDDATA, so i tried simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA) but

It just gave me this errors:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 5: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlfilter\xmlfilter.php
>   on line 65
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlfilter\xmlfilter.php on line 65
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlfilter\xmlfilter.php on line 65

At the end of the new file it write 'false?¿':

```
"LETRA_IMPRENTA":{},"LETRA_MAYUSCULA":{},"PANTALLA_VERTICAL":{},"PANTALLA_PEQUENA":{},"NAVEGADOR_CHROME":{},"SALIR_MITAD_BODY":{},"SALIR_MITAD_GUARDAR":{},"SALIR_MITAD_NOGUARDAR":{}}}falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse
```

Example of my xml:

```
<LANGUAGE><HELLO><![CDATA[hello]]></HELLO></LANGUAGE>
```

That's it my code:
[image]

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. If you have a problem parsing XML then (1) Don't show us your attempt to encode the results as JSON! (2) Show us the XML you are trying to parse!

Comment: @Quentin Ok, sorry, I am updating my post now.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What does `$xml` contain? Can you share a version of the XML file you try to read?

Comment: You keep editing the question, but you still haven't put the XML that is causing the problem in to it!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Don't link to an external file. Use one of the two strategies described under "Minimal" in the linked guide to reduce it to the problematic part and include it in the question.

Comment: @Nico Haase The [CDATA[xxx]] from xml that i want to pass to other file in json it hasn't convert it is just empty in the new file.

Comment: @Quentin I put a link to MEGA if u need to see the xml file

Comment: If we need to see the XML file, then it needs to be part of the question and not hosted externally.

Comment: @Quentin Ok, sorry, I am trying to explain my problem, I gave example of it :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/".$y);
> simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)
> ```

`simplexml_load_file` takes a file path in a string as input and returns a simple XML object. This is fine.

`simplexml_load_string` takes some XML in a string as input and returns a simple XML object. You are giving it a simple XML object as input, not a string. This is not fine.

Use `simplexml_load_file` **or** `simplexml_load_string`, not both.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know how to read CDATA? I mean with simplexml_load_file and json_encode it convert CDATA empty text

Comment: With `LIBXML_NOCDATA`